# How to save each string to a separate file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder including some files to open and read, extract some Persian words from them separately and join each set of words to make a sentence. Finally I want to save each sentence into a separate .txt file. But the problem is that the last sentence is saved in all the files. how can I fix it?

```
import os
import codecs



###opening the files from a folder in a directory
matches=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\Users\\Maryam\\Desktop\\New Folder"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".pts"):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, file))
print(matches)
print(len(matches))

###reading files 
for f in matches:
    with codecs.open(f, "r", "utf-8") as fp:
        text=fp.read().split('\n')
        #print(text)
        #print (len(text))

###converts one string to strings        

     for line in text:
         line_list=line.split()
     #print (line_list)


###extracting the persian words and removing the parantheses       
        list_persian_letters=['ا','آ', 'ب','پ','ت','ث','ج','چ','ح','خ','د','ذ','ر','ز','ژ','س','ش','ص','ض','ط','ظ','ع','غ','ف','ق','ک','گ','ل','م','ن','و','ه','ی','.','؟','،',':','!']

        output_words = [word for word in line_list if (word[0] in list_persian_letters)]
        output=[s.replace(')', '') for s in output_words]
        #print (output)
###joining the words as as sentence        

        sentence=' '.join(output)



###saving each sentence in a separate file 


        for i in range(1,16):

            with codecs.open ("F:\\New folder\\output%i.txt" %i, "w","utf-8") as text_file:
                text_file.writelines(sentence)
```

Comment: Remark aside : you could do `list_persian_letters="ABCDE..."` instead of `list_persian_letters=['A','B','C','D','E',...]`, as a string is a Sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All files are overwritten in each loop iteration. So you see only the result of the last iteration.

Change the outer loop to:

```
for i, f in enumerate(matches):
```

and

```
for j, line in enumerate(text):
```

and get rid of the 1..16 loop:

```
for i in range(1,16):
```

and modify:

```
with codecs.open ("F:\\New folder\\output%i_%i.txt" % (i,j), "w","utf-8") as text_file:
```

I hope you will change the code to get exactly what you wanted.